# What Happens if you runTransactionBlock on a parent node?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code:

```
public func emailExists(email: String, exists: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    
    let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: email)
    
    database.child(safeEmail).runTransactionBlock ({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        
        guard currentData.value as? [String: Any] != nil else {
            print("   Email doesn't exist")
            
            database.child(safeEmail).setValue([ *SomeData* ])
            
            exists(false)
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        
        exists(true)
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        
    })
}
```

If I were to runTransactionBlock on a main parent node, will that lock the whole database from being edited until the transaction is complete (or not)? Would this be a bad idea to implement if many users call this function simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions in the Firebase Realtime Database don't really lock nodes, but are instead compare-and-set operations.

When you run a transaction on a node, the client calls your callback with its current guess of the value of that node (typically `null` the first time). You then tell it what the new value for the entire node should become.

The client send both those values (the current and the new one) to the server, which checks whether the current value is the same as what the client guessed. If it it the same, it writes the result to the database. If it's not the same (as it typically won't be the first time), it tells the client the write was rejected and gives it the actual value of the node in the database. The client then calls your callback with that updated guess at the current value.

This repeats until the server is able to commit the new value (because the current value was unmodified), or until it runs out of tries.

---

Running the transaction higher up in the database node, means:

1. That you are requesting more data from the database.
2. That there's more chance of conflicting writes (known as contention) on the data.

It is recommended to run transactions as low as possible in the database, and it's actually quite common to move/duplicate data lower into the database to accomplish this.

Running transactions too high up in the JSON structure may lead to problems with contention, which often only occurs once you have sufficient concurrent users on your system, so it's best to prevent this early.